# How to organize or use pre-exsisting html into a new php application?

Tags: php

Looking for ideas on how to go about working with a large set of .html files (50,000+) that are preexisting.
What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to keep the same hierarchy, links etc... but add content to them via php or whatever etc..

To be able to organize or route them into a php application or my own cms. I have been thinking ways to do this and come up with a few ideas but hoping to get some feedback from some pros.

I really only need to create something that will get the data once and add it to a cms that I develop. I have a script that I wrote to be able to index and search etc.. but how to go about using the contents and adding to them while keeping structure has me swinging a little. Any thoughts?

---

UPDATE: I found some tips that made this easier for me as well

Use a .htacess file and ad:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

Then I can add includes into those files, I am note sure where to put this in the config file yet but will update when I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use a CMS like Wordpress, assuming your content follows some sort of regular structure, you could recreate the HTML frame as templates and then write a script that parses each HTML file and creates a post based on criteria like the HTML file name.

You can even match the file name by setting the slug on post creation, though you'll need a server rewrite rule to drop the .htm(l) if you intend to keep all the backlinks to the site.

I'm oversimplifying of course, as with 50,000+ files it isn't a trivial job to move all the data.

Perhaps automate it using something like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/

Comment: Not a bad idea, I worry about all the existing links etc. But I suppose it could be a great learning experience! I am going to try this out now and see what I come up with.

Comment: You know that is all I needed, the WordPress route didn't work but gave me the right idea to make it happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about it is to keep the html in a function which you require. Separate them logically as:

```
function output_html_one($link_here, $or_link_there...) {...}
function output_html_two($other_links...) {...}
```

When you want to output them with the files you have, just call the function, and it will be sent out. I am sure others will give you preferences. This allows you to give them access to variables through arguments, which is a downside, but it keep everything organized and provides some clarity as you can separate the raw html from the logic in your code. I am very curious to see what others say.

EDIT: I added $user inside of html_header so its clearer. For example, lets say you might want to check if a user is logged in. This gives you a way to tailor your html. Then you go to the files which contains this, you can jump in and out of the php tags in order to add dynamic content.

Comment: I see what you mean in terms of performance, but if you look at frameworks like code igniter, thats what they use, and it works quite fast. It depends on your implementation. But I think I misunderstood you. The only thing I would change from my implementation is instead of passing things like $title, you could just pass links. I will edit what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are on the same page, though I do get what you are saying.